# Using XHTML format for AMP tags

Tags: amp-html

Can i use the xhtml `<amp-img />` instead of `<amp-img></amp-img>`.
I see it works but is it supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the XHTML-form. That has nothing to do with AMP. XHTML self-closing tags are not supported in AMP.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its supported.
To confirm it yourself, you can add #development at the end of the url and check browser console. it will display any amp validation error.